# Activity transition in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to build pretty much my first android app.
I am also learning Kotlin at the same time. As it stands i can't seem to get activity transition to work.

This is the code of the main activity 
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    PdfButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
    fun onClick(v:View) {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, WebActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
    } } )


}
}
```

And this is the code of the second activity

```
class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web)


}}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: have you clicked button?

Comment: Activity transition required `Intent` and `Bundle` with `startActivity()`

Comment: @StanislavBondar bundle is not must

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kotlin, you can simplify OnClicklisteners using lambda expressions.
Try below code, it will work

```
PdfButton.setOnClickListener{
      val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, WebActivity::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Now you try this.

Comment: Good to hear this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer here [Activity Transition Koatlin](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity.html)